# Using a CASE function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle and am trying to build out some sql for the following scenario:

On EMPLOYEES table, if employee has ADDRESS3 not equal to ' ', populate this field with ADDRESS2 else, populate this field with ADDRESS1.

...

```
, ADDRESS_LINE2 = NVL(( 
    SELECT (CASE t2.ADDRESS3 != ' ' THEN t2.ADDRESS2 ELSE t2.ADDRESS1 END)
    FROM EMPLOYEES t2
    WHERE t2.EMPLID = PS_Z_EXS_EMP_TBL_T.EMPLID
), t2.ADDRESS1)
```

...

but it keeps giving me an error message about missing the right parenthesis.  When I comment this bit out though it runs fine.  DOes anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This appears to be missing the WHEN statement. `CASE WHEN t2.ADDRESS3 != ' ' THEN t2.ADDRESS2 ELSE t2.ADDRESS1 END` or `CASE t2.ADDRESS3 WHEN != ' ' THEN t2.ADDRESS2 ELSE t2.ADDRESS1 END`

Comment: This appears to be the answer :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CASE has two variants - both needs WHEN clauses.

One variant can have complete and complex boolean expression in each WHEN clause:

```
CASE
   WHEN t2.ADDRESS3 != ' ' THEN t2.ADDRESS2
   ELSE t2.ADDRESS1
END
```

In the other variant each WHEN clause contain values to be tested for the CASE expression:

```
CASE t2.ADDRESS3
   WHEN ' ' THEN t2.ADDRESS1
   ELSE t2.ADDRESS2
END
```

The last one cannot do != so therefore "reversed" logic ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need the `END` keyword at the end of a case expression:

```
CASE t2.ADDRESS3 != ' ' THEN t2.ADDRESS2 ELSE t2.ADDRESS1 END
```

Comment: Then check for a mis-placed closing parentheses.

Comment: `WHEN` was also missing.